# Saving in Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c

At abcViewController.m

```
Product *pro = [NSEntityDescriptioninsertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:_appDelegate.managedObjectContext];   
        pro.name = _nameText.text;
        [_context insertObject:pro];
        [_appDelegate saveContext];
```

saveContext in AppDelegate contains

```
- (void)saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        NSError *error = nil;
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }

    }
}
```

Any need of "[_context insertObject:pro];" at abcViewController.m for saving into coreData file from context????

Comment: And the question is... ?

Comment: `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:` and your save context is enough

Comment: Please show how do you create appDelegate variable

Comment: i got my data saved in the core data file. However i have doubt on the issue that how actually the data got saved, which method was invoked in order to save it whether ` [_context insertObject:pro] `  or ' [managedObjectContext save:&error] '.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `_appDelegate.managedObjectContext` and `_context` are two different `NSManagedObjectContext`'s, you don't need to explicitly call `insertObject` as you already inserted a new `Product` object with `NSEntityDescriptioninsertNewObjectForEntityForName`